# Overriding sql table structure

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`table_1` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`table_2` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `number` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The result that I want to get:
*table 1* and *table 2* are expected to be the same, table 1 is in my coworker workspace and I want to change it to table 2 **Without losing data**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `alter table`.  It should be fine:

```
alter table table_1 modify name varchar(256) not null;

alter table table_1 add number integer unsigned not null;
```

Notes:  the `not null`s actually assume that your table is empty (for `number`) and that `name` has no `NULL` values.  Otherwise, you will need a default values.